# If column B in excel file 2 matches Column B in excel file 1, output column A value in excel file 1 value to column C in excel file 2

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to put a name in column C in excel file 2 based on a number in column B in file 2 that is matched to column R in file 1. The name comes from column A in file 1.

```
File 1
A                R
John Doe         1234567
Jane Smith       8889911


File 2
B                C
1234567          "John Doe should appear here"
8889911          "Jane Smith appears here"
```

Comment: Why vba when a simple INDEX/MATCH formula will work?

Comment: Without vba in `C1`: `=INDEX([File1]Sheet1!$A$1:$A$2,MATCH(B1,[File1]Sheet1!$R$1:$R$2,0))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An index match will work. In file two, type this formula

=index(*DRAG AND CLICK THE ALL YOUR DATA IN FILE 1, which wil automatically link its location*,match(*THE CELL YOU ARE LOOKING UP*, *DRAG AND CLICK THE B COLUMN OF YOUR DATA in FILE 1*, 1)

The last 1 tells this formula to look in the first column of your data range in File 1.

The actual formula will look like this.

```
=INDEX([File]Sheet1!$A$2:$B$6,MATCH(A3,[File1]Sheet1!$B$2:$B$6,),1)
```